# How to privately publish Android apps over the net without giving away apk file?

Tags: android

I want to sell custom apps so I need to know how I can privately publish them over the net without giving away apk file.
Is there a way that I can give the customer a password that he/she will use to install the app only once from a website
without getting the apk file? After the installation the access to the download should be cancelled.

Comment: This makes no sense. You need the apk to install the app.

Comment: You could use something like HockeyApp, which is for beta testing - http://hockeyapp.net/features/

Comment: @VM4 So the app is not unpacked once installed on a device? I want to prevent them from using the file to install on other devices. Is Google Play giving people a copy of the actual file?

Comment: You can't really prevent people from reusing the apk.

Comment: @ataulm Thank you. I'll try to contact them whether they can remove the access once the download is done.

Comment: Why don't you want to distribute your apps over Google Play if you're going to sell them anyway? If people really wants to get hold of your apk, they will, you cannot prevent it.

Comment: @MishaLee I came up with a potential solution for you, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install apps without using an APK file, unless the target device is rooted.

Even Google Play downloads APK files for applications. They are stored in `/cache/download`, which can only be browsed with root access. Once downloaded, they get installed in `/data/app`, which also requires root access to read.

---

### Google Play alpha/beta testing

What you could do, as a workaround, is use the Google Play alpha/beta testing feature with a private Google+ Community. This will allow you to control who is able to download your application through Google Play, but it will not prevent them from rooting their device, and retrieving the apk.

You will get all the benefits of Google Play, and your customers wont notice any difference, once they've joined the Google+ Community.

[Use alpha/beta testing & stages rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. It still sound complicated for general public to retrieve apk file. It's enough to make it hard for them. Sorry, I'm still a beginner, what do you need to do to have root access?

Comment: This only applies to Google Play. Any other app store on Android requires "allow installation of apps from unknown sources". About rooting: The person needs to actively root his/her device. These days it's an easy process, but it also voids the warranty on most devices. Do a Google search to learn about rooting.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is have the first activity that starts up create a large random string from the device's id and then send that string to your server ( assuming you have one ).  If this is the first time your server receives a code for this app, let them in and store the code, then return a response of "OK" to your app,  if its not the first time, check if this is the code you stored previously, if not return "NO", if it is the right code return "OK".  then have your app shut down if it doesn't receive "OK" back from your server.  This of course adds extra cost and requirements to your app...

Comment: If the app requires network access, I would also suggest implementing a login and authorization feature to prevent public access

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider that. I do need to keep it simple for the customers and low cost for me, I'm not sure about installing additional apps.

Answer (score 0):

If they have to install it on their devices, they have the apk already, and there is no need to root access though, you can retrieve the apk with ES File Explorer in a second. What is your concerns, your codes? Or something else?